# How to limit the number of actors of a particular type?

Tags: scala, akka

I've created an actor to send messages to a chat server. However, the chat server only permits 5 connections per user. If I hammer my scala server I get error messages because my chat clients get disconnected.

So how can I configure akka so that my `XmppSenderActor`s only use a maximum of 5 threads? I don't want to restrict the rest of the actor system, only this object (at the path `/XmppSenderActor/`).

I'm trying this config since I think it's the dispatcher I need to configure, but I'm not sure:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /XmppSenderActor {
    dispatcher = xmpp-dispatcher
  }

  xmpp-dispatcher {
    fork-join-executor.parallelism-min = 2
    fork-join-executor.parallelism-max = 3
  }
}
```

This gives me an error though: `akka.ConfigurationException: Dispatcher [xmpp-dispatcher] not configured for path akka://sangria-server/user/XmppSenderActor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably try to configure a Router instead.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/routing.html

A dispatcher seems to deal with sending messages to the inbox rather than the actual number or Actor targets.

That configuration in particular could work for you:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /router {
    router = round-robin
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}
```

The `nr-of-instances` will create 5 childrens from the get going and therefore fill your needs.
You might need to find the right Router implementation though.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks dude.